# Populate object array with another object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an object array:

```
source_array = [
    {
        "prop1":"one",
        "prop2":"two",
        "prop3":"three"
    },
    {
        "prop1":"four",
        "prop2":"five",
        "prop3":"six"
    }
]
```

and declaration of `destination_array`:

```
destination_array: { prop1: any, prop2: any }[];
```

Now I want to populate `destination_array` so that I only take `prop1` and `prop2` from `source_array` like this:

```
[
    {
        "prop1":"one",
        "prop2":"two"

    },
    {
        "prop1":"four",
        "prop2":"five"
    }
]
```

I tried this:

```
this.objectArray = new Array(this.performances.length)
this.performances.filter(item => {
  this.objectArray.fill({'prop1':item.prop1, 'prop2':item.prop2})
});
```

but this will only return:

```
[
    {
        "prop1":"four",
        "prop2":"five"

    },
    {
        "prop1":"four",
        "prop2":"five"
    }
]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
this.destinations = this.performances.map(performance => ({
  prop1: performance.prop1,
  prop2: performance.prop2
}));
console.log(this.destinations);
```

A working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-array-properties?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is Array.map function

```
const destination_array = source_array.map(item => {
    return {prop1: item.prop1, prop2: item.prop2}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var source_array = [
    {
        "prop1":"one",
        "prop2":"two",
        "prop3":"three"
    },
    {
        "prop1":"four",
        "prop2":"five",
        "prop3":"six"
    }
];

var results = source_array.map(function(item){
  return {prop1 : item["prop1"], prop2 : item["prop2"]}
});

console.log(results);
```